# Not able to install Ghost.py

Tags: python, pip, ghost.py

I want to try [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/).
its documentation says that installation require [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) or [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/).
I have installed pyqt4-dev-tools using command `apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools` on my [Kubuntu](http://www.kubuntu.org/) 13.10.

I am getting error

> root@alok:~# pip install Ghost.py
>   Downloading/unpacking Ghost.py
>     Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Ghost.py (from versions: 0.1a, 0.1a2, 0.1a3, 0.1b, 0.1b2, 0.1b3)
>   Cleaning up...
>   No distributions matching the version for Ghost.py
>   Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log

I have installed PySide too still I am not able to install Ghost.py using `pip install Ghost.py`
using `pip` is so straight forward but I am not able to figure out what is wrong this time.
output of `/root/.pip/pip.log` is available at http://paste.ubuntu.com/7189458/

Comment: cant understand your ghost code

Comment: there is no code in the post. there is command `pip install Ghost.py` which is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem on OSX with PyQt installed via Homebrew.

Using `pip install --pre Ghost.py` made it work. This is also suggested in the `pip.log` you provide.